# Issue with netcat command in windows

Tags: spark-streaming, netcat

I have installed netcat for windows 8.

At the command prompt I am giving the command `nc -lvp 50050`.

I am getting a message "listening on [any] 50050 ..."

But I am not able to type in any message. Can any one please help me what could be wrong.

I am actually trying to test spark streaming to test the messages that I am typing in host 50050

Comment: I also tried using the command `nc -l -p 50050`. When I give this command the cursor will go to next line but I am not able to type in anything over there. So I had to press cntrl-c to exit out of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the command "nc -vvv -l -p 50050" I am able to start the port 50050. From which I could type in something and listen from SparkStreaming.